# Ruby OpenSSL encrypt with hex key returns empty string

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, base64, aes

Hi all this is my first question here. I'm gonna go straight to the point. Thanks for your help in advance.

I'm trying to encrypt an string using a base64 key created from a 32 byte hex string and a salt also in base64 created from a 16 byte hex string and AES-128-CBC algorithm.

This is the code (ruby):

```
base64_key = 'NTQ2ODY5NzMyMDY5NzMyMDYxNmUyMDY1Nzg2MTZkNzA='
base64_iv  = 'NTQ2ODY5NzMyMDY5NzMyMA=='

# create an OpenSSL Cipher to encrypt the user name
encrypter = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-128-CBC')
encrypter.encrypt

# the key and iv must be a byte array
encrypter.key = Base64.decode64(base64_key)
encrypter.iv  = Base64.decode64(base64_iv)

# add the username to encrypt
enc_string = encrypter.update 'somestring'
# push the rest of the string encrypted
enc_string << encrypter.final

# the enc_string value must be sent encoded as base64
enc_string = Base64.encode64(enc_string)
```

The problem is the enc_string ends up being empty.

I tried this code with a base64 key generated from a phrase like

```
key = Base64.encode64('This_is_test')
encrypter.key = Base64.decode64(key)
```

And this works.

Any insights? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use AES-256 (evident from the 256 bit key), why are you requesting an AES-128-CBC cipher and not AES-256-CBC?

Comment: Tried using AES-256-CBC and now sometimes I get something and sometimes and empty string. Also it should always be the same string, isn't it?

Comment: Works fine for me every time I run it

Comment: It works (http://ideone.com/L8OynE), so maybe your environment is broken.

Comment: I found out that for coldfusion you need some extra java policies files to make this work. Do I need extra libraries for ruby to use this encryption? extra libraries that don't get installed by default?

Comment: Ok I've find out how to make it work. I had to add `encrypter.padding = 1` after creating the encrypter. And also use the `AES-256-CBC` as Artjom B suggested. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

After some back and forward I figured it out how to make it work.

I had to add the `encrypter.padding = 1` after instantiating the Cipher.

This is how the code looks now:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

base64_key = 'NTQ2ODY5NzMyMDY5NzMyMDYxNmUyMDY1Nzg2MTZkNzA='
base64_iv  = 'NTQ2ODY5NzMyMDY5NzMyMA=='

# create an OpenSSL Cipher to encrypt the user name
encrypter = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
encrypter.padding = 1
encrypter.encrypt

# the key and iv must be a byte array
encrypter.key = Base64.decode64(base64_key)
encrypter.iv  = Base64.decode64(base64_iv)

# add the username to encrypt
enc_string = encrypter.update 'somestring'
# push the rest of the string encrypted
enc_string << encrypter.final

# the enc_string value must be sent encoded as base64
enc_string = Base64.encode64(enc_string)
```